# JMeter Regular Expression Extractor is not extracting within single quotes

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to extract this and it's not working for some reason.

The pattern works for all others but not this:

```
Line: test.com', '2018-07-25T15:42:55');">
```

Extract using Regular Expression:

```
test.com', '(.+?)');">
```

Trying to extract value - `2018-07-25T15:42:55`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `)` character which is reserved character in regular expression, so either remove it:

```
test.com', '(.+?)'
```

Or escape it:

```
test.com', '(.+?)'\);">
```

Comment: Thanks @user7294900 :). it's working with test.com', '(.+?)'